# Optimize python code

Tags: python, optimization

I have the following code:

```
    inputFile = open('C:/Abaqus_JOBS' + JobDir + '/' + JobName + '-3_4.inp', 'r')
    for line in inputFile:
        fileData.append([x.strip() for x in line.split(',')])

    fel=0
    for row,data in enumerate(fileData):
        if data[0]=='*Node':
            row_nodes = row #number of the row when data='*Node'
         if data[0]=='*Element' and fel==0:
            row_elements2 = row
            fel=1

    for row,data in enumerate(fileData[row_nodes + 1:row_elements2]):
        nodes.append(data) #data between '*Nodes' and '*Element'
```

However, it runs very slow (minutes) in the python interpeter of an external program (I have to run the script here because I need to access a database of results produced by this program). How can I optimize it?

EDIT:
I close the `inputFile` at the end of the code: `inputFile.close()`

Comment: What's in the `....`?

Comment: how big is the file? Are you sure you're closing the file properly after reading it?

Comment: @Patashu, jozzas: question edited.

Comment: Are you forced to write it in Python, or are you able to write it in a faster language?

Comment: @Patashu: I can write in C++.... but I'd have to learn it.

Comment: How many rows large is the file?

Comment: It may reach 3000 lines or so.

Comment: Have you profiled the code to see what taking the most time?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well, you first store the file line by line, then search for the first occurence of "*Element" and the last occurence of "*Node", and finally store what's between them.

An optimization I see is that you can go from 3 parsing of your file to a single one:

```
inputFile = open('C:/Abaqus_JOBS' + JobDir + '/' + JobName + '-3_4.inp', 'r')

go_storage = False
nodes = None

for line in inputFile:
    if line[0] == "*Node":
        # Reset what has already been memorized
        nodes = list()
        go_storage = True
    elif line[0] == "*Element":
        break
    elif go_storage:
        nodes.append(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could think along the lines of regular expressions:

if I understand it right, you want to get the data between the keywords *Node and *Element in some file, right?

well you could try something like:

```
import re

S = open('C:/Abaqus_JOBS' + JobDir + '/' + JobName + '-3_4.inp','r').read() 
Data =  re.finditer( "\*Nonde([.\n]*?)\*Element", S )
```

That should give you a list of strings that are found in between the Tags "*Node" and "*Elements"

I hope that was what you were trying to do.
Cheers